# WP8.1 Automatic Update of XAP Certificate

Tags: ssl, windows-phone-8, certificate, xap

We currently have a Windows Phone 8.1 app located in the app store which has been signed with a symantic certificate. When the renewal time came for the certificate we had to update the xap and push out the new xap to all the users which means the user is aware of an update being required.

My question, is there a way to automatically update the currently installed application with a re-newed certificate when the application connects into out private servers to download new data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging and reading I've finally come to the conclusion that their isn't a way to do what I want directly. Instead the best path I can find at this point in time is to use this:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/server-cloud/products/microsoft-intune/default.aspx

This appears to offer a full suite of Mobile Device Management including certificate renewal.